# how to merge a list with a datatable while keeping the list format as output

Tags: r, list, merge, data.table, stringr

I have a list containing vector as its elements in R

Example:

```
## -- reference data
tr_data <- data.table(code = c("S00000170","K00000178","S00000164","S00000167"), name = c("A","B","C","D"))

## -- mylist to join a reference
data <- c("S00000170,K00000178,S00000164","K00000178,S00000167")
mylist <- str_split(data, ',')
mylist

# [[1]]
# [1] "S00000170" "K00000178" "S00000164"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "K00000178" "S00000167"
```

I would like to merge mylist and tr_data and conserve a list format

```
## -- my output
mylist_name

# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "B" "D"
```

I know I could use a for loop but is there a better and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`, i.e.

```
lapply(mylist, function(i)tr_data$name[match(i, tr_data$code)])

#[[1]]
#[1] "A" "B" "C"

#[[2]]
#[1] "B" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert `data` into a `data.table`, set key/index then perform a join

```
DT <- data.table(code=unlist(l <- stri_split_fixed(data, ',')), 
    g=rep(seq_along(l), lengths(l)))

setindex(DT, code)
setkey(tr_data, code)
tr_data[DT, on=.(code)][, 
    .(.(name)) , g]$V1
```

Or

```
setindex(DT, code)
setkey(tr_data, code)
DT[tr_data, on=.(code), name := name][,
    .(.(name)), g]$V1
```